# Can I Generate the Set of Chars from Regex Pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I have regular expression for example [ABC], [A-Z], [0-9], [A-Z,0-9], [^A-Z]. Can I generate set of chars from regex pattern? 
Thank you.

EDITED:
In Java. I found that http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html random(int count, String chars) class exist for generating random code.

But i need to generate code using regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`String::Random` in perl may be a little help to you, it takes regex and gives values of satisfied data.

```
use String::Random;
my $string_gen = String::Random->new;
print $string_gen->randregex('\d\d\d'); # Prints 3 random digits
```

or

```
#Prints 3 random printable characters
print $string_gen->randpattern("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that regular expressions can become way more complicated then the character sets you show.

If you limit yourself to character sets, I see two viable approaches:

- Parse the character sets yourselves, implementing the rules for well, regexp character classes.
- If you can/want to ignore Unicode characters, just loop over all 256 characters (chr(0) - chr(255)), trying to match the regexp against the character using some regular expression engine.

Please include some details of which language you are working in next time, makes it easier to give an example.